# Get items for list

Tags: c#, ravendb

I got the following documents:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    string Id;
    string Owner;  //"users/1"
    string TodoListId;  //"todolists/1"
    string ParentId; //"treenodes/1"
}

public class TodoList
{
    string Id;
    List<TodoItem> Items;
}

public class TodoListItem
{
    bool IsCompleted;
}
```

How can I fetch all items for the current user which has not completed? Should I redesign any of the documents?

I want something like:

```
from all treenodes belonging to the current user
load all todolists
and return all active items within those lists
```

But within one server roundtrip

**Update 2**

Here is how I tried to do it with two queries (SelectMany is not supported):

```
var todoListIds = _dbSession.Query<UserTreeNode>()
    .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
    .Select(x => x.TodolistId);
var nodes = _dbSession.Query<Todolist>()
    .Where(x => x.Id.In(todoListIds))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Items.Where(item => !item.IsCompleted));
```

Comment: does the `TodoList` have a `List` of `TodoList`s?

Comment: what is the relation between todolistitem and todolist? is there a typo in the List<TodoList> Items?

Comment: Not clear a relation between all these types presented here. Con provide some related to question code.?

Comment: I guess you've forgotten to paste `TodoList`' `Id` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make RavenDB only return a sub-set of a single doc, so in your case you need to get the entire `TodoList` and then just filter on the client.

You can do this in a single network call using the [Include feature](http://ayende.com/blog/4584/ravendb-includes), this should work:

```
var todoListIds = _dbSession.Query<UserTreeNode>()
    .Include(x => x.TodoListId)
    .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
    .Select(x => x.TodolistId);

foreach (var userListId in todoLisIds)
{
    //This won't cause an extra network call, because the session will have already loaded it
    var todoList = _dbSession.Load<TodoList>(userListId);

    //In-memory filtering to get the outstanding items
    var activeItems = todoList.Items.Where(x => x.IsCompleted).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have provided is not the real code but the following gives you uncompleted items from a todolist object.

```
list.Items.Where(q => q.IsCompleted == false);
```

Comment: No, its not real code, but a sample model which represents my real (but much larger model). Your code do not give me **all** unfinished items for a specific user. It gives me all items within one list.

Comment: @jgauffin the question is not clear itself. how are you storing todoLists, inside List<TodoList> ?

Comment: "TodoList" and "TreeNode" are stored as document collections in raven which is shown by `"todolists/1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on it and I believe you need a different approach, (please note its something related to architecture and I can't be 100% sure about it, it might need some modification). It seems like you want to create a TODO List for the user. I think, its may be better if you could structure it in a way That

- A User Can have one or more To Do List(s) (I have assumed one To Do List in my example)
- One To Do List Item can have multiple instances of Actual work to Do

I would follow a structure similar to below:

```
public class User
{
    public string ID { get; set; }//.... All User Attributes AND

}

public class TodoList
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public User owner { get; set; }

}

public class TodoListItem
{
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public TodoList parent { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

Above I have a class for User which is currently representing your user. Then I have a class for ToDoList which is holding User class object (**not the id of user**) then I have ToDoListItem which is holding ToDoList object as parent. 
If we look through database perspective than we have One to Many relationship between User and ToDoList and again one to many in ToDoList and ToDoListItem. 

 Now if you want to search user with incomplete work to do , just try the following linq query:

```
    var query = from t in listTDL
                where t.IsCompleted == false
                select t.parent.owner;
```

You might need these lines to fill a test data structure:

```
User user = new User() { ID = "User1" };

TodoList td = new TodoList() { Id = "TD1", owner = user};

List<TodoListItem> listTDL = new List<TodoListItem>();

TodoListItem tdl = new TodoListItem() { ItemID = "TDL1", ItemDescription = "Frist Item", IsCompleted = false, parent=td };
                listTDL.Add(tdl);
                listTDL.Add(new TodoListItem() { ItemID = "TDL2", ItemDescription = "second Item", IsCompleted = true, parent = td });
listTDL.Add(new TodoListItem() { ItemID = "TDL3", ItemDescription = "third Item", IsCompleted = true, parent = td });
listTDL.Add(new TodoListItem() { ItemID = "TDL4", ItemDescription = "fourth Item", IsCompleted = false, parent = td });


List<User> userList = new List<User>();
userList.Add(user);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but: A) you are not holding a reference to the user, but a copy of it. I did so in my sample too, by mistake. b) The node structure is mandatory (tree like structure + the same list can be shared between many users and all have their own tree). c) So the todolist can't have a reference to a user since it is shared.

Comment: @jgauffin, I didn't know that User and ToDoList have a many to many relationship, do the ToDoList and Items have many to many relationship as well ?

Comment: No. An item can only exist in one list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do:

```
var result = todoList.Where
(
  x => nodeList.Any
  (
    y => y.Owner == "ownerId" && y.TodoListId == x.Id
  )
).SelectMany(x => x.Items).Where(z => !z.IsCompleted);
```

P.s. I'am not familiar with RavenDB so showing just an idea

Comment: Nice, but you forgot the most important thing: The `TreeNode` maps users to todolists. And there is only a string key in it, so the problem can't be solved without RavenDB knowledge.